# Start deepin system monitor from command line

Tags: debian, terminal

I have installed in my debian distro the deepin system monitor and, when i open it the graphical way, it works! Is there a command to open the monitor from the terminal?

I want to do this so i can asign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: What does `command -v deepin-system-monitor` say?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk this: /usr/bin/deepin-system-monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[deepin-system-monitor.desktop](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-system-monitor/blob/master/deepin-system-monitor.desktop)
shows the following `Exec=` line:

```
Exec=deepin-system-monitor
```

[README.md](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-system-monitor/blob/master/README.md)
also mentions:

```
./deepin-system-monitor
```

What means that after installing `deepin-system-monitor` you can start
it simply:

```
deepin-system-monitor
```

You don't have to use `./` at the beginning because it's already in
your `$PATH` as confirmed by `command -v deepin-system-monitor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the deepin system monitor from your terminal directly by -

```
/usr/bin/deepin-system-monitor
```